# How to send NSData as key and IV for CCCrypt

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I need to AES128 encrypt a 16 byte block of data using a key and an IV to a 16 byte AES block.

Every CCCrypt example I've seen takes in (NSString *) for key and IV. My Key and IV are NSData 16 bytes. I've converted the NSData into hex strings but the result is not correct. I get an AES block of 32 bytes when I do it that way.

So my question is, what do I have to do to get NSData to be read into CCCrypt as a const void * ?

```
- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv theData:(NSData *)theData
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [theData length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [theData bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);


    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You are specifying PKCS7 Padding. PKCS7 adds at least 1 byte of padding, so encrypting 16 bytes will push you into 2 blocks of 16 bytes = 32 byte of encrypted data.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I just put that in to test. I did get 16 bytes out when the padding wasn't there. I'm asking how to convert  16 byte NSData to be the const void * input for ivPtr and keyPtr.

Comment: ECB mode does not use an IV, perhaps you need CBC mode which is the default.

Comment: Thanks @zaph. I've read a lot abut this including your helpful answers to many others. If CBC is the default AND I don't want padding, how do you specify no options to options?

Comment: Just specify 0 for CBC and no padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ (NSData *)AES128:(NSData *)dataIn
         operation:(CCOperation)operation  // kCC Encrypt, Decrypt
               key:(NSData *)key
           options:(CCOptions)options      // kCCOption PKCS7Padding, ECBMode,
                iv:(NSData *)iv
             error:(NSError **)error
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( operation,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES,
                       options,
                       key.bytes, key.length,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes, dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError"
                                         code:ccStatus
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        dataOut = nil;
    }

    return dataOut;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zaph but still getting a 32 byte result. The dataIn, key, and IV are all 16 bytes. I've tried AES and AES128, I do have PKS7Padding in and this is a CBC block. I thought when you passed in all 16 byte pieces of data, you're supposed to get 16 bytes out.

Comment: With using padding some padding must always be added so when data that is a multiple of block size is passed in one block of padding must be added. See: [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Comment: This really helped @zaph. I have to encrypt and send to a service that decrypts. I was told they were using CBC and PKCS7padding but were only expecting 16 bytes. When I added the padding option, it gave me 32 but it resolved when I sent it. I would up vote your response but I don't have enough of a rep! Thanks again.

Comment: If the input to be encrypted is 16 bytes and PKCS#7 padding is being used 16 bytes of padding will be added. But I have seem developers dropping padding if the input data size is a multiple of the block size even though this is incorrect. You saw the PKCS#7 information in the previous link. If PKCS#7 padding is specified the last byte is examined and it specifies the number of padding characters, it has to be there so at least one byte of padding must be added. So your problem is how to deal with the Bozos. 

Comment: It is impossible to have a block size of 16-bytes (which AES has) and have input data of 16-bytes and use PKCS#7 padding and have the encrypted output be 16-bytes. So I guess these Bozos do not really want PKCS#7 padding so don't specify it if the input data size is a multiple of the block size. This will fail under some circumstances.