# AES CBC Encryption With PKCS7Padding Has Different Results In Java And Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I have created an application for Android in Java and used `Cipher` class to encrypt data with AES. Now I wanna take that algorithm into iOS with `CommonCrypto` class. The code works but has different results.

This is the code in **Java**:

```
public static String Decrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len = b.length;
    if (len > keyBytes.length)
        len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] results = new byte[text.length()];
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    try {
        results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Erron in Decryption");
    }
    return new String(results, "UTF-8");
}

public static String Encrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len = b.length;
    if (len > keyBytes.length)
        len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    System.out.println(keyBytes);
    System.out.println(keySpec);
    System.out.println(ivSpec);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(results);
}
```

This is the code in **Objective-C**:

```
+ (NSString*)AES256EncryptData:(NSString*)data WithKey:(NSString*)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = data.length;

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          data.UTF8String, dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

+ (NSString*)AES256DecryptData:(NSString*)data WithKey:(NSString*)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = data.length;

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          data.UTF8String, dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

**Update 1:**

Data: `text to encrypt`

Key: `testkey`

Java *(desired)* Result: `7ptTEyImNz9KgC96+JPFXQ==`

Objective-C Result: `U7FAVHi01q0Hhf+m9NsKjw==`

Comment: Please post the results and the desired result.

Comment: @JulienLopez Edit The Post With Sample Data

Comment: **Super insecure code above.  Never use your key, or any portion of it, as an IV, EVER.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the Objective-C code. You should use same method in both Java and Obj-C. You can use this code in order to make it return the same results:

**AES.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

@interface AES : NSObject 

+ (NSData *)Encrypt:(NSString *)data WithKey:(NSString *)key;
+ (NSString *)Decrypt:(NSData *)data WithKey:(NSString *)key;

+ (NSData *)AESOperation:(CCOperation)operation OnData:(NSData *)data key:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

**AES.m**

```
#import "AES.h"

@implementation AES

+ (NSData *)Encrypt:(NSString *)data WithKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [self AESOperation:kCCEncrypt OnData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] key:key];
}
+ (NSString *)Decrypt:(NSData *)data WithKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self AESOperation:kCCDecrypt OnData:data key:key] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

+ (NSData *)AESOperation:(CCOperation)operation OnData:(NSData *)data key:(NSString *)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Do not use the key for the iv, they need to be different and the iv should be different for each encryption. The iv does not need to be secret.

Comment: @zaph i'm agree with that but here, i've just translated the java code for him

Comment: @zaph You may need to check the padding size in both languages. And check your iv out. These are the most important factors. In my case key and iv was the same. But it is not the right way

Answer (score 0):

In the java code, you are using an IV parameter:

```
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
```

In the Objective C, the IV parameter is set to NULL:

```
CCCrypt(..,   NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
```

That aside, the IV parameter should be some random values and not you secret key (or part of it). The idea is to outpout different cypher text and prevent block pattern matching

Comment: how can I have that IV in Obj-C? Sorry I'm new in Cryptography

Comment: There is plenty of example on internet or stackoverflow (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229572/how-to-send-nsdata-as-key-and-iv-for-cccrypt). If you want the same result in ObjectiveC and java, you would need to apply the same logic to get your IV. However, as noted before, it is better to keep the IV random

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an iv to the ObjC code, not NULL.

Do not use the key for the iv, instead create a iv of random bytes, prepend it to the encrypted data for use on decryption. In ObjC you can create an random iv with `SecRandomCopyBytes`:

```
uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, kCCBlockSizeAES128, iv);
```

Output:

> iv: 8617dcf92de01ac2c0b92763b206b3f5